# Collision probability in a game

Tags: probability, game-theory

Consider a system where time is slotted, and assume that each time slot there are $S$ available boxes; these boxes are not the same from slot to another.
 Suppose there are $N$ users, each of which has a probability $p$ of having something to send at a slot.
If a user has something to send at slot $t$, then he randomly chooses a box (from the $S$ boxes) at each of slots $t$, $t+1$ and $t+2$; so in total he chooses 3 boxes.

For a user of interest, a *collision* occurs if at each of the slots $t$, $t+1$ and $t+2$ at least one of the other ($N-1$) users makes the same choice of box as the user of interest.

Question: What is the collision probability of other users with the user of interest?

**My attempt**:
- Let $P_c$ denote the collision probability. Let $P_{nc}$ be the probability of no collision, so $P_{c}=1-P_{nc}$. 
- There is no collision between the user of interest and any other user if: *(a)* the latter one does not send in at least one of the slots $t$, $t+1$ or $t+2$, *(b)* the latter one sends in each of the slots $t$, $t+1$ and $t+2$, and makes the same choice of box as the user of interest at each of these slots.
- If $P_{nc,i}$ denotes the no-collision proability of user $i$ with the user of interest, we have $P_{nc,i} = 1-p^3 + p^3 (\frac{S-1}{S})^3$, where $1-p^3$ represents the probability of (a) and  $p^3 (\frac{S-1}{S})^3$ represents that of (b).
- Thus, $P_{nc}=P_{nc,i}^{N-1}$, and $P_{c}=1-P_{nc,i}^{N-1}$.

Comment: I had a hard time reading the paragraph "There is no collision...." To start, you refer to a "collision between the player of interest and [some other player]." You've never defined collision as a relation between two players, only as an event that happens to one player. So what is the definition of a collision between two players?

Comment: Not sure the rules make sense.  Are you distinguishing between "choosing" a slot and "playing" in the slot?  If $A$ chooses slot $1$ then he is automatically playing in $2$ as well, yes?  But if the probability of playing in $2$ is the same as the probability of playing in $1$ then it would appear to follow that he plays in $2$ iff he plays in $1$, which I doubt is what you mean.

Comment: When you subtract $p^3$ you are trying to subtract the chance the player does not play at any time slot, but the problem indicates you make one choice at slot $t$ and play all three slots if you decide to play at slot $t$.  It also seems you could have one player decided to play in slot $t-1$, so play $t-1,t,t+1$ and match our player at $t$, then another player does not play $t$ but does play $t+1$ and matches our player at $t+1$ and $t+2$.

Comment: For b you seem to be requiring that one given other player collide at all three time slots, but I read the question to allow it to be three different players that collide.

Comment: @lulu Each user will try to play in each slot; $p$  is the probability that a user play in a slot. You are correct, if he plays in e.g. slot $1$, then he chooses a ball in each of slots 1, 2 and 3. I am not sure if I have to suppose that if he plays in  slot 1 then he cannot play in 2 and 3; I am not sure if this will simplify or complicated the analysis.

Comment: @din Whether a player can play in both slots 1 and 2 certainly needs to be clarified. Furthermore, if she can play in both 1 and 2, does she then choose two balls in slot 2 (one for playing in slot 1, one for playing in slot 2)?

Comment: @Y.Forman I have edited the question, by adding an assumption that if a player plays at e.g. slot t, then he cannot play (again) at slot t+1 and t+2.

Comment: @din Thanks. One final rules clarification -- is $p$ is probability that a player plays at slot $t$, _given_ that she did not play at slot $t-1$ or $t-2$?

Comment: @Y.Forman Yes, you can consider this definition of $p$ if the first assumption is made.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for pointing out this issue. I have edited the question. Regarding your first comment, I am not sure I fully understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Your edit seems to contradict the original.  There seems to be confusion between playing and choosing.  In the original playing at $t$ means choosing at $t,t+1,t+2$.  Under the second, he can play again at $t+1$.  Does that mean he chooses twice at $t+1$?

Comment: As I say, I think the rules are very unclear.  As a suggestion:  try to simulate the process.  That will do two things:  first (and most importantly) it will force you to clarify the rules.  Second, it will give you a numerical approximation to the result, which you can use to test your formula once you have one.

Comment: @RossMillikan Playing at slot t means choosing randomly a ball in each of slots t, t+1 and t+2. If the second assumption is made, then this same user with probability p plays at slot t+1, meaning that (if he plays) he chooses randomly a ball at each of t+1, t+2, and t+3; in this case he will choose 2 balls in each of slots t+1 and t+2, because he played at t and t+1.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for your comments. I have edited the question one last time. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to simulate the process. Btw  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not understand the chance a user chooses a ball at time $t+1$.  Is it $p$?  Is it the chance he didn't start at $t-1,t$ or $t+1$ where he can't overlap, so $1-(1-p)^3$?  Could he start at both $t$ and $t+1$ and choose two at time $t+1$?

Whatever it is, call it $q$ that any given user chooses a box at any time.  Assuming our user chooses a box at each of $t,t+1,t+2$, the chance he has a match with a given other user at time $t$ is $\frac qS$.  The chance he has no match with any other user is then $(1-\frac qS)^{N-1}$.  The chance of a match is $1-(1-\frac qS)^{N-1}$ at each time slot, so the chance of three successive matches is $(1-(1-\frac qS)^{N-1})^3$